# Error using an editable DT Table with the crosstalk package in R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I would like to use the crosstalk package to link  the rows of an editable DT DataTable to the points of a Leaflet Map on a shiny app using a shared dataset. The idea of this part of the app is that the user uploads a file with street addresses, which are geocoded by API and then the outputs update to show the points. The user should be able to  alter the coordinates (if incorrect or inaccurate) which should automatically update the map.

To use crosstalk on a DT table, I have set `Server=FALSE` in `renderDT()`. However, to allow changes to the DT Table to automatically update on the map, I have used the `replaceData()` function with a `proxyDataTable()` which as I understand, only works on the server side - clashing with the crosstalk `server=FALSE` setting. This then results in the following error when I edit the table:

> *DataTables warning: table id=DataTables_Table_1 - Invalid JSON response. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/1*

Below is a simplified example.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(leaflet)
library(crosstalk)



ui <- fluidPage(

  fluidRow(column(6,DT::dataTableOutput("Table")), 
           column(6,leafletOutput("Map")))
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  #This would usually be an fileinput 
  x <- data.frame(id = c(1,2,3,4),
              lat = c(60,65,70,75),
              lon = c(60,55,40,45))

  y <- reactiveValues() 
  y$data <- x  

  observe({

    SharedTable <- SharedData$new(y$data)
    output$Table <- DT::renderDT({

      datatable(SharedTable,
                filter = "top",
                editable = TRUE,
                rownames = FALSE,
                class = "compact", 
                selection = "single",
                options = list(
                  columnDefs = list(list(className = "dt-center", targets = "_all"))
                )) %>%
        formatRound(c("lat", "lon"), digits = 6)
      }, server = FALSE)


      output$Map <- renderLeaflet({
        leaflet() %>%
          flyToBounds(min(y$data$lon), min(y$data$lat), max(y$data$lon), max(y$data$lat)) %>%
          addProviderTiles(providers$OpenStreetMap) %>%
          addAwesomeMarkers(data = SharedTable, 
                            lng = ~as.numeric(lon),
                            lat = ~as.numeric(lat))
      })
    })


    proxy = dataTableProxy('Table')

    observeEvent(input$Table_cell_edit, {
      info = input$Table_cell_edit
      i = info$row
      j = info$col + 1
      v = info$value
      y$data[i, j] = DT::coerceValue(v, y$data[i, j])
      replaceData(proxy, y$data, resetPaging = FALSE, rownames = FALSE)
    })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Changing the coordinates does actually work as intended on the app so is it possible to suppress this error message or will this potentially cause issues down the line? Or is there another method to link these two outputs? Sorry if I am misunderstanding anything on how these packages work, I am quite new to R Shiny.

Thanks!